# glibc installation: cannot compute suffix of object files

Tags: gcc, configure, glibc

I am trying to install glibc 2.3.2 on my Ubuntu using gcc v3.4.6, but have faced a problem. Glibc should be built for mips. I tried it on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines, but still the same problem. The input parameters to `configure` are:

```
BUILD="i686-pc-linux-gnu"
HOST="i686-pc-linux-gnu"
TARGET=mipseb-linux
export CFLAGS="-O2 -mips2 -mabi=32 -fno-PIC -mno-abicalls"
export CZFLAGS="-mips2 -mabi=32 -fno-PIC -mno-abicalls"
./configure --build=${BUILD} --host=${HOST} --target=${TARGET} ....
```

the error is:

```
...    
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

and the config.log:

```
...
configure:2941: $? = 1
configure:2945: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2967: gcc-3.4 -c -O2 -mips2 -mabi=32 -fno-PIC -mno-abicalls  conftest.c >&5
cc1: error: invalid option `ips2'
cc1: error: invalid option `abi=32'
cc1: error: invalid option `no-abicalls'
configure:2970: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| #line 2950 "configure"
| /* confdefs.h.  */
|
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "c-library"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "glibc"
| #define DO_STATIC_NSS 1
| #define USE_REGPARMS 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2984: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I first thought the problem is that I have not set `BUILD`, `HOST`, `TARGET` correctly, so I changed `HOST` to `mipseb-linux`, but the error and log are still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong. Since I had installed a couple of different GCCs on my machine, the `configure` and `makefile` were picking the wrong GCC. Even though they were picking GCC with the right version (3.4), they were picking GCC for i686 instead of picking a mips-compatible GCC. There are two solutions for that:

1. Removing the wrong GCC from your PATH. I ended up not doing that for some reason.
2. Defining the following variables prior to running `configure` and `make`:

   TARGET=mipseb-linux
   CC=${TARGET}-gcc-3.4.4
   BUILD_CC=gcc
   AR=${TARGET}-ar
   RANLIB=${TARGET}-ranlib